# Extract error info from log files

Tags: logging, ssh, putty

I am monitoring the real time server logs through putty by running the command 'tail -f console-20160622.log' ,I want to capture all the error information from the logs which are being generated on the putty console.Is there any command which can write my error info to a text file from the console or any other alternative method to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "grep"?

The command that could help you is the following:

```
tail -f console-20160622.log | grep "INFO"
```

GREP will filter the log lines and just will show these that contains the "INFO" string

Answer (score 0):

If you are using syslog or rsyslog each has a cooresponding **.conf** file.

```
if     ( \
            $msg contains 'error' and $msg contains 'OUT=' \
        and $msg contains 'SRC=' and $msg contains 'DST=' \
        and $msg contains 'PROTO='\
) \
then           -/var/log/messageshere.log
```

Obviously you can add more,less, or different conditions.

You can even log to mysql

then   :ommysql:192.168.0.1,syslog,syslog,syslog;**name of template**

Additional options:

```
# => all acpid messages for debuging (uncomment if needed):
if     ($programname == 'acpid' or $syslogtag == '[acpid]:') then \
       -/var/log/acpid

# => up to notice (skip info and debug)
if     ($programname == 'acpid' or $syslogtag == '[acpid]:') and \
       ($syslogseverity <= 5 /* notice */) \
then   -/var/log/acpid
&      ~
```

Also

```
# Emergency messages to everyone logged on (wall)
*.emerg                                         :omusrmsg:*

# enable this, if you want that root is informed
# immediately, e.g. of logins
*.alert                                root
```